# Can Istio measure latency between clusters in any multicluster model?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, latency, istio-prometheus

I'd like to know if Istio can provide latency metrics between clusters (regardless of response time of a service) in any of multi-cluster models as I was unable to figure it out from the docs.

I did not see in the docs any metrics that would suggest such measurement taking place as it is done for example in Liqo peer latency: https://docs.liqo.io/en/v0.6.1/usage/prometheus-metrics.html